# Makefile:635: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?). Stop

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to create a package, compile it and install it in OpenWrt. However, I have trouble getting past this error:

```
Makefile:635: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.
```

Here's the line 635 in Makefile:

```
define Package/qt4-drivers-gfx-vnc/install
$(INSTALL_DIR) \
$(1)/usr/lib/Qt/plugins/gfxdrivers
$(CP) \
$(PKG_INSTALL_DIR)/usr/lib/Qt/plugins/gfxdrivers/libqgfxvnc.so \
$(1)/usr/lib/Qt/plugins/gfxdrivers/
endef

$(eval $(call BuildPackage,qt4)) /*this is the line 635*/
$(eval $(call BuildPackage,qt4-gui))
$(eval $(call BuildPackage,qt4-demos))
$(eval $(call BuildPackage,qt4-examples))
$(eval $(call BuildPackage,qt4-network))
$(eval $(call BuildPackage,qt4-sqlite))
$(eval $(call BuildPackage,qt4-mysql))
$(eval $(call BuildPackage,qt4-openssl))
```

Comment: That line itself is very unlikely to be the problem. What are the lines around that line? (And that tab in the call is pointless if not wrong).

Comment: Ok I'm going to update the code and add the lines around that line so you can see if there's a problem.

Comment: What is the `BuildPackage` define? Did you edit/modify any of these makefiles?

Comment: No I didn't make any changes. Here's the file if you want to see the whole thing  https://github.com/anarsoul/qi-openwrt-packages/blob/master/qt4/Makefile

Comment: You should probably be using a macro for the string `/usr/lib/Qt/plugins/gfxdrivers` since you wrote it out at least three times.  It'll be easier to fix accurately if you do have a macro.  It's the DRY principle again -- don't repeat yourself.

Comment: That's not a remotely complete makefile. Is there a special setup you need to use that with? Also line 635 of that file is nowhere close to the line you indicated in your snippet.

Comment: The thing is I'm trying to create and compile qt4 package for my OpenWrt SDK. I've been trying out qt4 makefiles on the internet to create a package, then compile and then install it. This makefile is the only one, so far, that could be "detected" in menuconfig.